# creating a sysupgrade binary from existing install

Tags: linux, openwrt

Is there a way to create a sysupgrade binary from an existing install of OpenWRT? ... i.e. if I have OpenWRT loaded on a device, and configured in a certain way (packages, software ... etc), can I then create a sysupgrade that would pass the entire configuration of the system along to other devices?

Perhaps someone could recommend, or direct me to a resource.

I have looked here:

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.backup

Will any of those methods help me to create a sysupgrade from an existing install?

Perhaps I am missing something... Thanks!